# how can i create/insert details of a login member into mongodb using php?

Tags: php, mongodb, connection

I'm new to PHP and MongoDB. I'm creating a quiz game using notepad++. The player has to login to access the quiz. I have created the initial guest user in notepad++. Now, for a registration form, I want the data to be stored in MongoDB, but I'm really lost. I've tried searching google, youtube and stackoverflow for people with the same problem but still couldn't find anything specific..can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. Do you have a code sample of what you have tried so far that you are having trouble with?

Comment: $connection= new MongoClient(); 

//Connect To Database

   $db= $connection->selectDB('Quiz');
   
      
//Create Collection

   $members = $db-member>;
   
     
//Insert Document
      
   $doc= array(
                "username" => "player2"
       "password"=> 123 ,
       );

    $members->save($doc);

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.phpgainers.com/content/mongodb-php-beginners).

Comment: thank you for making that tutorial..really helpful. But for some reason im not being able to connect to the mongodb through php.

Comment: My local host is xampp. The php version is 5.6.8. The driver I have used is php_mongo-1.5.7-5.6-vc11. I hope this is the right one. I put it in xampp>php>ext and renamed it as guided. The extention is added to the php.ini file which was in the php folder. I don't know where im going wrong. Im stupid enough to be stuck on the first step but it'll be helpful if you could direct me.